Unruly passenger on plane gets flight diverted. Can other passengers sue?
I was reading an article on CNN about an unruly passenger causing a flight to have to turn around.  The Australian magistrate ordered the passenger to pay a fine and for the cost of the fuel that needed to be dumped to land the plane.
I have heard of lots of similar incidents over recent years.  I have definitely heard about these passengers being fined by various government agencies.
However, I have never heard of another passenger on the plane suing the unruly passenger.  Im sure in a plane filled with dozens to hundreds of passengers that was delayed, cancelled, or diverted that someone was harmed financially or emotionally.  Perhaps they missed a deadline, job interview, a funeral, etc.
Perhaps these lawsuits dont make the headlines?  Have passengers ever sued other passengers that caused issues on flights?  What about other forms of public transportation, like cruises/boats, busses, etc?

Very interesting question, as the action of the unruly customer seems to be within the natural and probable consequence that were set as a limit in Palsgraf v. Long Island Railroad Co., 248 N.Y. 339, 162 N.E. 99 (1928)

Liability for delays and failed performances by airlines, at least of the airline itself, is regulated by statute and regulation and treaty in the U.S. and most other jurisdictions. It is possible that non-statutory liability is pre-empted by these statutes, although I don't know for certain whether this is or is not the case. But that would be the first issue I would research if I was trying to answer it. I've never heard about lawsuits like this either, which makes me suspect that there is some form of pre-emption.

You generally can’t generally sue for pure economic loss
Economic loss is a loss that only appears on a balance sheet and not as a physical injury to a person or thing. Consequential economic loss that directly follows from that physical damage is recoverable, but pure economic loss that is independent of physical damage is not.
That’s why you can’t sue someone for wasting your time, despite the obvious social benefit that would flow from this. 
A contract can allocate the risk of pure economic loss and where it does, this is recoverable under contract law. Some jurisdictions have allowed some pure economic loss from torts to be recoverable but these are limited in their scope and application. AFAIK, no common law jurisdiction would allow such a claim as you describe.

Courts have been less strict on the economic loss rule in cases involving intentional torts, however, like this one. Alternatively, the passengers might be third-party beneficiaries of the contract between the passenger and the airline. Another possibility might be that a court in the criminal case might award the passengers restitution as part of a criminal judgment.

I assume the unruly passenger was breaking the law, so would that make a difference?

In practice, I’d expect the airline to pay passengers compensation for the flight delay without much effort from the individual passengers. Getting more compensation from the unruly passenger would be much more work (going to court, providing evidence and finally getting money from them), even if possible it’s unlikely to happen. Much more likely that the airline would try.

@gnasher729 on likelihood: if passenger unruliness is correlated with alcohol consumption, the greater availability of alcohol in higher classes of service suggests that there may be a greater likelihood for unruly passengers to have a lot of money. Then again, passengers with a lot of money can probably hire more and better lawyers, which probably more than compensates for the first factor, leading to, indeed, a very low likelihood of getting much from individual unruly passengers.
